# How to have a centered div with dynamic size (text) and that its side divs are visible without indicating its size?

Tags: css, html

How to have a centered div with dynamic size (text) and that its side divs are visible without indicating its size?

The div "text" has no size, only up and be focused. 
The side divs (bg-bg-left and right) should be visible and width auto.

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="bg-left">The width should be automatic.</div>
    <div class="text">This text should be centered and may increase the width.</div>
    <div class="bg-right">The width should be automatic.</div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.cont{ width:500px; height:15px; background:purple;}
.bg-left { float:left; width:50px; height:15px; background:red; }
.text { float:left; height:15px; max-width:200px; background:green; white-space:nowrap; }
.bg-right { float:left; width:50px; height:15px; background:red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PnY2Q/4/

Comment: Dynamic, text center and width auto and side div width auto too

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code for centering the div and content

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#page{display:table;overflow:hidden;margin:0px auto;}
*:first-child+html #page {position:relative;}/*ie7*/
* html #page{position:relative;}/*ie6*/

#content_container{display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
*:first-child+html #content_container{position:absolute;top:50%;}/*ie7*/
* html #content_container{position:absolute;top:50%;}/*ie6*/

*:first-child+html #content{position:relative;top:-50%;}/*ie7*/
* html #content{position:relative;top:-50%;}/*ie6*/

html,body{height:100%;}
#page{height:100%;width:465px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
       <div id="content_container">
               <div id="content">
                     <p>your content</p>
               </div>
       </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q92Lb/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating, you can do it easily with table display:

```
.cont{display:table; width:500px; height:15px; background:purple;}
.bg-left { display:table-cell; width:50px; height:15px; background:red; }
.text { display:table-cell; height:15px; max-width:200px; background:green; white-space:nowrap; }
.bg-right { display:table-cell; width:50px; height:15px; background:red; }
```